# really dumb question with NSMutableArray and addObject

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

where I'm wrong??

oldEvents is NSArray...

```
NSMutableArray *oldIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0; i<[oldEvents count]; i++){
    [oldIDs addObject:[(NSDictionary *)[oldEvents objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"]];
}

NSLog(@"Count: %@", [oldIDs count]);
```

I can't figure out this problem!!! I receive EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to log oldIDs count

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

İn case of `NSLog(@"Count: %@", [oldIDs count]);`

you have to write

```
NSLog(@"Count: %d", [oldIDs count]);
```

and check that `(NSDictionary *)[oldEvents objectAtIndex:i]` has value for key id.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't releasing oldIds somewhere? The code looks all right to me.